# Aws Media Converter with SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

Is there a way to connect AWS Media Converter events to SNS instead of CloudWatch ? I've seen a lot of examples with Cloud Watch but  i do need to use SNS istead, does anyone has an experience on it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. More specifically, you can get the messages in both CloudWatch and SNS.  You do this by creating a CloudWatch Rule to forward matching events from CloudWatch to a SNS topic you specify. The Rule supports an optional filter which you can also specify; see my example below.

Once event messages arrive at the SNS Topic, they get forwarded to all the subscribers to that Topic (email addresses, lambda functions, Slack (via lambda Fn), etc).

A typical CW Rule for MediaConvert will resemble:

```
{
  "source": [
        "aws.mediaconvert"
      ],
  "detail-type": [
   "MediaConvert Job State Change"
  ]
}
```

And the target will be the SNS Topic of your choice.

I hope this helps you out!